# How do I portforward a port correctly & what are my options?

Tags: c#, networking, router, portforwarding

I created this project a few days ago where I can portforward a port so I can host a server.
How it works.

1. I start the server and people cant join
2. I start the application & I press "Open"
3. It opens the port (see the code below)
4. Now the port is open and people can join

---

If I were to login to my router with 192.16.0.1 and fill out the name and the password and then navigate to the portforward tab I could do the same time with the exact outcome.
Here is the main issue. my friend who is runing on a cellular net, with other words he's running with a mobile net. I think it's called a

> Mobile Broadband

When he tried to portforward it's not doing anything at all. but when I run it on all of my PC's at home it works like a charm.

The issue I am facing now is, what could cause him to not be able to use this application and what are my option? Should I try a different library?

I'm currently using Mono.NAT

https://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/upnp-port-forwarding-the-easy-way/

CODE

```
private bool btnOpenWasClicked = false;
        private bool btnCloseWasClicked = false;
        [STAThread]

        private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnOpenWasClicked = true;
            NatUtility.DeviceFound += DeviceFound;
            NatUtility.StartDiscovery();

        }


private void DeviceFound(object sender, DeviceEventArgs args)
        {
            if (btnOpenWasClicked == true)
            {
                INatDevice device = args.Device;
                Mapping minecraftTCP = new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 25565, 25565);
                Mapping minecraftUDP = new Mapping(Protocol.Udp, 25565, 25565);
                minecraftTCP.Description = "MinecraftTCP";
                minecraftUDP.Description = "MinecraftUDP";
                device.CreatePortMap(minecraftTCP);
                device.CreatePortMap(minecraftUDP);

                foreach (Mapping portMap in device.GetAllMappings())
                {
                    Debug.Print(portMap.ToString());
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Port 25565 has been opened.");
                DialogResult diag = MessageBox.Show("This is the IP you will give to your friends: " + device.GetExternalIP().ToString() + ":25565" + " Do you wanna copy the IP? ",
                    "Success", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                if (diag == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText(device.GetExternalIP() + ":25565"));
                    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
                    thread.Start();
                    thread.Join(); //Wait for the thread to end
                }
            }

            if (btnCloseWasClicked == true)
            {
                INatDevice device = args.Device;
                device.DeletePortMap(new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 25565, 25565));
                device.DeletePortMap(new Mapping(Protocol.Udp, 25565, 25565));
                MessageBox.Show("Port closed.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you calling Clipboard.SetText on a new thread?

Comment: Because otherwise it throws me a really weird error. Feelf ree to debug it and check what it is, I cant think of the error on the top of the dome.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it works for you is because your internet access point (e.g your router) supports the [IGD Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol). The NAT library that you use just makes it simpler to access this protocol. Your friend uses an access point (wireless modem, smartphone, etc.) that either does not support the IGD Protocol or has it disabled.